# Meaning of "There is no reason why something should not be done?"

Tags: wh-questions

I'm not clear the real meaning of "There is no reason why something should not be done"

Does it mean that

> "it is not allowed to get something done in any circumstance."

or

Does it suggest

> "Although something has not been done, actually we are allowed to get it done."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"There is no reason why something should not be done" means that someone does not have a good reason, or any reason, to **not** do something.

In simpler terms, it means you **can** do it since there is no reason/excuse, or what @KateBunting has suggested, "it would be perfectly acceptable to do it".

Comment: Well, not necessarily 'have to', but 'it would be perfectly acceptable to do it'.

Comment: @KateBunting The word "Can" indeed conveys a better and meaningful explanation I could easily understand.